# Получить id товара в js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Есть страничка с товарами. Рядом с каждым товаром иконка "Добавить в корзину".

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на эту иконку в js приходил id товара, который человек добавил в корзину.

```
 <input type="hidden" id = "idProduct" name = "idProduct" value = "{{$p->id}}">
```

Id товара хранится в скрытом поле. Однако при нажатии на корзину я всегда получаю Id лишь первого товара в БД. То есть, он всегда равен 1.
Вот так пробовал получить:

```
var idProduct = $("#idProduct").val();
```

Вот общая форма:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h3>{{$p->name}}</h3>
            <img src="{{$p->image}}" width="200" height="200"><br>
            <h3>{{$p->price}}<a href="#" id = "cartIcon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"  name = "spanIdProduct" onclick="addProductInCart()" style="float: right; margin-right: 15px" value = "{{$p->id}}"></span></a></h3>
            <input type="hidden" id = "idProduct" name = "idProduct" value = "{{$p->id}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо повесить ивент на нажатие, в вашем коде вы получаете ид первого элемента(у вас много полей с одинаковым ид, это не верно, ид может быть только один):

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form">
    <div class="col-lg-2 product">
        <h3>{{$p->name}}</h3>
        <img src="{{$p->image}}" width="200" height="200"><br>
        <h3>{{$p->price}}<a href="#" id = "cartIcon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"  name = "spanIdProduct" onclick="addProductInCart()" style="float: right; margin-right: 15px" value = "{{$p->id}}"></span></a></h3>
        <input type="hidden" class = "idProduct" name = "idProduct" value = "{{$p->id}}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </div>
</form>


$('.product').click(function () {
       alert(this.find('.idProduct').val());
});
```

обратите внимание на то что в этом коде я изменил ваш ид на класс

Comment: Но ведь класс тоже будет у всех одинаковый. Или как это работает?) И нельзя ли повесить просто onclick?

Comment: @Андрей тут дело в самой концепции ид - это уникальность, как в таблице, а класс в свою очередь может быть у многих элементов

Comment: А как я обработаю нажатие на idProduct, если это скрытое поле?) Или вы просто саму идею показали?

Comment: @Андрей поправл ответ

Comment: Как-то не особо работает

Comment: @Андрей что именно?

Comment: Как минимум ошибка, что this.find не является функцией

Comment: @Андрей $(this).find('.idProduct').val(). В любом случае я хотел всего лишь подсказать идею

Comment: `$(this).find('.idProduct')` ищет в потомках `.idProduct`, их естественно нет. Найдите ближайшую форму и ищите в ней. Вообще непонятно зачем вам и обработка клика и  форма.

Comment: Форму я сделал потому что думал, что нужно сделать из каждого товара форму, отправлять её и уже потом из неё вытаскивать id

Comment: как я понимаю у него есть много продуктов, каждый продукт - форма, при нажатии на кнопку(в форме) или еще что ему надо вытащить ид продукта. Все нормально

Comment: Тогда надо событие сабмита формы обрабатывать, а не клик. `form.serialize()` сразу все поля и привезет, даже ничего получать не надо.

Comment: Да, именно так. Пытаюсь корзину в интернет магазине сделать. И хочу хранить массив Id в сессии, чтобы потом товары в корзине отобразить

Comment: Вот вопрос. А как сделать обработку отправки формы, если для этого нужен submit, а у меня нажатие на span?

Comment: @Андрей заменить спан на баттон

Comment: Жаль. Думал есть другой какой-то вариант)

Comment: Ну или если совсем все плохо - вызывать `$(form).submit()` при клике.